# irreducible polynomials over the $p$ adic number

Tags: number-theory

Are there some necessary conditions on the coefficients of a monic, irreducible polynomial $\Phi$ over a local field?

Comment: The constant term must be non-zero.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible, then the newton polygon of $f$ has exactly one slope.

Comment: The first comment is not quite right: try x. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A corollary of Hensels lemma: 
If K is a field that is complete with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value, then for an irreducible polynomial $P=\sum{a_iX^i}$ of degree $n$ we have 
max($|a_i|$)=max($|a_0|$,$|a_n|$)

Comment: Perfect answer: Actually, I was hoping exactly for a statement of this flavor.

Comment: Corollary 4.7 in Chapter 2 of Neukirch "Algebraic number theory".